# How to recursively calculate from bottom to top using PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, tree

I want to calculate a value that will be carry forward from bottom to the top.

[image]

For example from the image above, I have this State A,B,C,D,E under Brunei country that each have rating value of 6,4,4,3,3.

To calculate the value, I need to plus all the value and divide by the number of states.

(6 + 4 + 4 + 3 +3) / 5 = 4

The rating value only available at state level, and after calculate it will be be bring up to his parent, summed and divided by the number of child.

My current solution use nested for loop, however it only works if I know the exact depth of the hierarchy. So if I add WORLD become a children of the PLANET, I need to manually add another nested for loop to calculate the rating, which is not very elegant. I am looking to convert the current solution into a more dynamic solution.

Blank function :

```
function getRating($place_id){
    //do other things
    //get ratings from all states in the country, summed and divide by the number of states
    //return result of average rating 
}


$world_id = 1;
$asia_id = 3;
$brunei_id = 7;

getRating($world_id);
//expected result : 5

getRating($asia_id);
//expected result : 4

getRating($brunei_id);
//expected result : 4
```

Current solution :

```
//calculate continent rating

          foreach ($subcontinents as $key => $subcontinent) {

               //calculate sub-continent rating

               foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {

                    //calculate country ratings

                    $rating_count = sizeof($state_ratings);

                    $total_country_achievement = 0; 

                    foreach ($state_ratings as $key => $state_rating) {

                         $total_rating_achievement = 0;     
                         $state_achievement = $state_rating->value;

                         $total_rating_achievement = $total_rating_achievement + $state_achievement;

                    }

                    $total_country_achievement = $total_rating_achievement / $rating_count;

               }            

          }
```

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump()` of the input data? And why is there a hard-coded variable value in your inner loop?

Comment: @jeroen hi the harcode just want to illustrate the rating value, for var_dump() actually I can get the value I want using the sample solution above, however it is not very elegant since I need to manually add another for-loop if there is other parent exist

Comment: What is your expected value? Are you looking for $total_country_achievement for a specific country, or an array of all country values, or you just out after the world value, or the entire tree?

Comment: You need to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to [travers the tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: @AronCederholm hi expected value if user choose ASIA, he will get value 4. If he choose South-East-Asia, he will get value of 6. However all the ratings only held up by states.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a recursive function to traverse the tree, calculating the average value for each level. Something like this (adapt to your own needs).

```
function getValueOfLeaf($node) {
    if (is_array($node)) {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
            $sum += getValueOfLeaf($value);
        }
        return $sum/sizeof($node);
    } else { // not an array
        return (int) $node;
    }
}
```

To get a country value or a continent value, do this:

```
getValueOfLeaf($planet['earth']['asia']['south-east-asia']['brunei']; // get brunei states average
getValueOfLeaf($planet['earth']['europe']); // get average value of all country averages in Europe
getValueOfLeaf($planet['earth']); // get average for earth
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you function recursive like this

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        5,
        [[10,[6,4,4,3,3],5,5],4,2],
        6
    ];
    function getAvg($arr){
        foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
            if(is_array($value)){
                $value = getAvg($value);
            }
        }
        $avg = array_sum($arr)/count($arr);
        echo "\nAverage of  : ".implode(", ", $arr)." => ".$avg;
        return $avg;
    }
    $avg = getAvg($arr);
    echo "\nAverage of all is : ".$avg;
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/874201

Comment: Hi maybe I misunderstand your code, but only value 6,4,4,3,3 is the exact rating, others is the average from this value and carry up above, and continue to average for each children

Comment: @NediSidi : yes this is exact array form you draw

Comment: @NediSidi : or share your php array data sample ?